# Add disjunctive tag refinement in Algolia JS Helper

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm trying to do a disjunctive filter by tags in Algolia but there's no documentation about it. This is what i'm doing actually:

```
helper.addTag('Shangai').search();
```

That will filter all the documents that have the Shangai tag.
But i need to get also all the documents that have the Brooklyn tag.

```
helper.addTag('Brooklyn').search();
```

After doing that i get 0 results because algolia is using the AND operator as default to search in tags, so is looking for documents that have Shangai AND Brooklyn. What i need Shangai OR Brooklyn.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use the `setQueryParameter` method.

```
helper.setQueryParameter('filters', 'Shangai OR Brooklyn').search();
```

Also I would recommend you enclose your tag values between double quotes in case they contain spaces.

```
helper.setQueryParameter('filters', '"Shangai" OR "Brooklyn"').search();
```

Note that `setQueryParameter` supports [all documented Algolia search query parameters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/search/#search-parameters).